# Why does my Current Regulative Diode not regulate current well?

Tags: diodes, current-source, constant-current

I recently ordered several E153 CRDs from Semitec (data sheet [here](https://www.mouser.sg/datasheet/2/362/crd-1407.pdf)) to maintain a steady current to an LED (data sheet [here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1975638.pdf?_ga=2.201521105.1913450884.1556252663-521642061.1551237749&_gac=1.238690868.1554197934.EAIaIQobChMIxJjjvI6x4QIVlhOPCh3CQwkDEAAYASAAEgKhTPD_BwE)). Mistakenly, I didn't read the "Dynamic Characteristics" portion of the data sheet before ordering which seems to suggest the E153 doesn't line regulate very well, with current peaking at 10Vin and dropping off thereafter. The "Basic characteristics" graph however gave me the impression that any Vin above 10V would maintain a steady pinch-off current.

My questions is, is this expected behavior of a CRD or is the E153 just bad? Can I still use them as a constant current source for my LED?

For my purposes I need to use a 9V power source which droops by at most 0.5V under the heaviest load we require. Temperature will range from 25C to 30C worst case. The consistency of LED brightness is crucial for its purpose; we need the LED to maintain +-0.1mA of current. We bin our LEDs to ensure they all output the same brightness at a specific current.

[image]

Sorry for the basic question, and thank you!

Comment: Can you share your nominal/min/max supply voltage and your operating temperature range?

Comment: For an indicator lamp, current isn't critical.   Unless your power supply fluctuates a LOT, the regulator diode seems fine.   If there's a metrology reason you want regulated light, don't expect input current to be the only variable, LEDs age.

Comment: I've edited my question to address these questions. For my purpose I need the LED to be precise to +-0.1mA, and we couple that with binning the LEDs to ensure they output the same brightness.

Comment: A 20mA +/- 0.1 is 0.5% and LEDs typically vary over a wide range. If you need 1% LEDs I used to supply these in the over 10Cd ~20 Cd range @20mA . current regulation to 0.5% is easy but never with these parts over a wide 10:1 voltage range. Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a single JFET, and probably a resistor, packaged as a diode. This won't be very accurate. The "voltage reference" used is the JFET's threshold which depends on temperature, which depends on voltage and dissipation. This, plus other JFET properties, mean it will vary quite a lot. It's still decent if you want a somewhat regulated current, with one part, and it is much better than a resistor if the voltage will vary a lot. It is not adequate for your application.

If you need something a lot more accurate and stable, try this:

[image]

TL431 is cheap, readily available, low noise, accurate and stable with temperature.  It will adjust the current drawn from pin "A" to keep pin "REF" at 2.5V above pin "K", via feedback through the internal error amp. This adjusts Q1's base voltage to control LED current.

I wired the BJT this way to make sure the base current (which depends on temperature and BJT) is not included in the regulated current.

For a 10mA current in the LED, set R2 = 250 ohms. Adjust accordingly.

This will cost maybe 20c and result in excellent stability. Main source of LED brightness variations should be air currents changing the LED temperature...

Comment: Thanks, I might just try this out!

Answer (score 1):

> My questions is, is this expected behavior of a CRD or is the E153
>   just bad? Can I still use them as a constant current source for my
>   LED?

You can, but YMMV like you have found out, the diode curve is not that flat. If you do need a current regulating diode in this family, a E101 or E301 or E501 would be a better choice.

If you need a stable current source in a two terminal device, use a constant current diode. Or if you need a settable source, use a FET or JFET current source.

[image]
Source: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/experiments/chpt-5/jfet-current-regulator/

Comment: I'm curious as to why they would market it as a "current regulative diode" then, if it cannot maintain the same current across a range of line voltage. From my tests on the E153, load regulation is subpar as well, even though supply voltage well exceeds load voltage.